# Sencha - Navigating Forms

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I am working in Sencha Touch version 2.4. I am trying to navigate forms. I have a button on the main form and want it to navigate to another form. This is my code for the button:

```
var loginform = Ext.create('widget.loginform'), 
    mainView = this.getMainView();                      
mainView.push({
    xtype: "loginform",
    title :"login"
});
```

But I keep getting this error:

Account.js?_dc=1462803352442:36 Uncaught TypeError: mainView.push is not a function

Comment: `push` [function](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-event-push) is only available for `Ext.navigation.View` class. ¿Are your sure that `this.getMainView()` is returning your navigation view?

Comment: this.getMainView() was not returning the navigation view. Thanks a lot. Its working